# wordpress single-{posttype}.php

Tags: wordpress

I have copied and modified the single.php file as decribed below:

```
 http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types
```

in order to add a custom html file to it.

is it possible to create a post with the normal procedure on the dashboard but that would call that new single-{posttype}.php instead of the single.php ?
meaning being able to choose with template to use from each time .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is a plugin for that:

> #### [Custom Post Template](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-template/)
>
> Provides a drop-down to select different templates for posts from the post edit screen. The templates replace `single.php` for the specified post.

Otherwise, you may want to check the filter hook **[`template_include`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/57214/12615)**.